# AKS upgrade from 1.14.8 to 1.1.7.7

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Can I upgrade the AKS version directly from 1.14.8 to 1.17.7 rather minor versions upgrade.

This upgrade is on Production AKS with 5 nodes. Just want to be extra cautious before doing.

Any advise on this?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful please accept and upvote so future users will know it's right

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you can upgrade to 1.17.7 using the following command:

```sh
az aks get-upgrades --resource-group %RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME% --name %CLUSTER_NAME% --output table
```

In my case, I run aks version 1.16.10 so I can upgrade to 1.17.7 directly.

**output:**

[image]

More information about [Upgrade an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster).

Be aware that I haven't tried to upgrade my aks version, therefore, I don't 100% sure that the upgrade won't cause any harm to the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want to skip all the minor version and directly upgrade it to 1.17.7 from AZ CLI as from portal, I have to all the minor versions one by one, which is very time consuming as we have 5 nodes .

Comment: As I mentioned, this could be possible. check using the command I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes releases a new version each 4 months.AKS maintains only 3 versions under Azure support. There is very nice youtube video that tells you to upgrade AKS kubernetes version using blue/green strategy with rollback in case things dont go well. Hope that link works for you as I have been using for all of my version upgrades.

[Kubernetes/AKS Blue/Green upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFcuIQaGbHw&t=5s)